# Database hits for related object in get_absolute_url in django

Tags: django

I'm building an app that lists podcasts and their episodes.

On the podcast page, I need to list episodes with links to the individual episode pages. To make human readable URLs, i'm using the slug for both the podcast and the episode. This is causing a lot of database hits. Here's the get_absolute_url function:

```
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        kwargs = {
            'show_slug': self.podcast.slug,
            'pk': self.id,
            'slug': self.slug
        }
        return reverse('episode_page', kwargs=kwargs)
```

How do I make this more database efficient, because for shows with 100s of episodes, this is querying the database a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things you can do. One, use [**`cached_property`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/utils/) to cache the method, so that it will reduce DB calls for repeated hits for same object.

```
from django.utils.functional import cached_property

@cached_property
def get_absolute_url(self):
        kwargs = {
            'show_slug': self.podcast.slug,
            'pk': self.id,
            'slug': self.slug
        }
        return reverse('episode_page', kwargs=kwargs)
```

Or better, have a cached property which is separate from `get_absolute_url`.

```
cached_absolute_url = cached_property(get_absolute_url)
```

Secondly, you can use [**`select_related`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) for loading FK data beforehand. For example:

```
episodes = Episode.objects.select_related('podcast').all()

for e in episodes:
   e.get_absolute_url()
```

Comment: What are the drawbacks of using the `@cached_property` decorator on `get_absolute_url`? I am surprised it's not recommended in the docs by default? I don't understand the use case to have a separate `cached_absolute_url`

Comment: That is just an example on how you can use `cached_property` on a method.